# Proper way to push to JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called 'inputs' that I want to push some values to.

I am wondering if this is the correct way to do so:

```
inputs.push(name: $('#uploaderName').name(), value: $('#uploaderName').val());
```

#uploaderName is the ID of a form field with the value I want pushed.

FYI, the 'inputs' array is created like this:

```
var inputs = data.context.find(':input').not(':button');
```

I have also tried this with no luck:

```
inputs.push({name: $('#uploaderName').attr("name"), value: $('#uploaderName').val()});
```

To explain a bit more, at the end of this script it calls:

```
data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
```

and then that data is passed off to a PHP script. I need to be able to add a few values to 'inputs' before inputs.serializeArray() is called.

Comment: No, because you're pushing an object.

Comment: inputs is made up of some field names and the values, I just need to be able to add a few more name/value pairs to the already generated 'inputs' variable.

Comment: Are you using a library like jQuery or Zepto? `.find(':input').not(':button')` to me suggests that `data.context` and `inputs` will be array-like [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) collections rather than actual `Array`s. If so, they won't have `.push()` methods. But, you can get an `Array` from them with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2).

Comment: The script I am working with uses jQuery

Comment: I also added a bit more info to my question

Comment: Can you provide your code `html` and `js` with jsfiddle?

Comment: @Suman, not really, because it needs to interact with a backend PHP script to see the end result.

Comment: why you can't just intialize the array soemthing like this  `var inputs =[];` as it's seem you need simple array, on which you need to push objects?

Comment: @Suman, the inputa variable is filled by the script, and the content changes very often. I needed a way to just add a couple of values to it, in the same format the script was using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `jQuery` collections, you can include additional `Element`s with [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).

```
inputs = inputs.add('#uploaderName');
```

jQuery collections aren't actually `Array`s. They're just array-like, meaning they have a `length` and numeric properties, but they won't have `Array` methods like `.push()`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to tell what type of data 'inputs' is so we know how to properly add to it?

Comment: @SherwinFlight Sorry. Just updated the snippet. `.add()` creates a revised collection rather than mutating the original, so you have to store the result.

Comment: Should it be '#uploaderName' like you have or $('#uploaderName')?

Comment: @SherwinFlight Both should work. `.add()` can accept either a [`selector`](http://api.jquery.com/add/#add-selector) or a [`jQuery object`](http://api.jquery.com/add/#add-jQuery-object).

Comment: The way you had it in your answer worked fine. I am accepting your answer. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the object, so use `{...}` to make the object first, and store it into `inputs` array, like

```
inputs.push({name: $('#uploaderName').name(), value: $('#uploaderName').val()});
//----------^----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

**Or**

```
var myObj  = {name: $('#uploaderName').name(), value: $('#uploaderName').val()}; 
inputs.push(myObj);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, but I added some info to my question